# Google Sheets - formula for expense sheet

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets

I need a formula that will help me calculate the $ expense amount for my milage rates.

Here is my sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PPFuFWbxWi9iIdtYBJvnSNB1j1cjjQutepF3hnpGoFM/edit?usp=sharing

On the tab that's expenses, I need to check the year of my date in Col A (because different years have different rates), then check Col D to see if it says Milage, then check Col E for what type of milage (there are 4 types), then return the number input in Col I times the appropriate rate for that year and type of milage. I have a table set up with the rates in another tab.

I'm thinking it will be a long IF and AND formula. Any help would be great!

Comment: Under Essentials log at the end of the columns

Answer (score 0):

In 'Essentials Log', I've changed the format of your year start-end dates to state the year you're referencing. I've added a column for "Milage".

[Expense Reference Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHIJr.png)

In `'Expenses'!M2`, I tried this and it seems to work:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(iferror(if(isblank(A2:A),"",I2:I*vlookup(D2:D&year(A2:A)&E2:E,query({'Essentials Log'!Y2:Y&'Essentials Log'!Z2:Z&'Essentials Log'!AA2:AA,'Essentials Log'!AB2:AB},"Select *"),2,false))))`

[Working Example Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCuGu.png)

Have a look (I copied your example sheet): [Milage expense](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MzHv6e4NC6i0BW5iI5p1wH9Or-VwfaQIm-Tz2B8qaxo/edit#gid=932163240)

Comment: It seems to be on the right track but its returning the value that's in Col I. I'm wondering if this would be better as a script.

Comment: I've changed some things and it's working on my end - it's a bit of a cumbersome formula but it's probably simpler than using script.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with creating an app script.

I realized I didn't want to use a formula because in my $ col most entries will be keyed in and so I didn't want to copy and paste a formula every time.

Here is the code if anyone might need it. I added it to the menu so the calculation is done with a click.

```
function expenseMilageCalculation() {
  var auditionsSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var expensesTab = auditionsSheet.getActiveSheet();  
  var activeCell = expensesTab.getActiveCell();
  var activeRow = activeCell.getRow();
  var expenseDate = expensesTab.getRange(activeRow, 1).getValue();
  var expenseYear = expenseDate.getFullYear();
  var expenseType = expensesTab.getRange(activeRow, 4).getValue();
  var expenseDetails = expensesTab.getRange(activeRow, 5).getValue();
  var numMiles = expensesTab.getRange(activeRow, 9).getValue();

  var essentialsLogTab = auditionsSheet.getSheetByName("Essentials Log")

//2018 Business Milage
if (expenseYear == 2018 && expenseType == "Milage" && expenseDetails == "Business") { 

  var milageBusinessRate2018 = essentialsLogTab.getRange(3, 27).getValue();
  var dollarMilesDeduction = numMiles * milageBusinessRate2018
  expensesTab.getRange(activeRow, 8).setValue(dollarMilesDeduction)

}

//2019 Business Milage
if (expenseYear == 2019 && expenseType == "Milage" && expenseDetails == "Business") { 

  var milageBusinessRate2019 = essentialsLogTab.getRange(8, 27).getValue();
  var dollarMilesDeduction = numMiles * milageBusinessRate2019
  expensesTab.getRange(activeRow, 8).setValue(dollarMilesDeduction)

}
```